# How to add custom context in windows explorer to run excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to export Easting and Northing coordinates from Excel to plot in autocad. The coordinates are from a log file that is saved in .npd format (txt).

```
Sub drawplinecad()

Dim ActiSheet As Worksheet
Dim acadApp As AcadApplication
Dim acadDoc As AcadDocument
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim acadPol As AcadLWPolyline
Dim dblCoordinates() As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim minbound(0 To 2) As Double
Dim maxbound(0 To 2) As Double
Dim min1 As Double
Dim max1 As Double
Dim min2 As Double
Dim max2 As Double


warning = MsgBox("Selected coordinate will be drawn in active Autocad drawing." & vbCrLf & "Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo, "Plot selected EN to polyline in AutoCAD")

Select Case warning
'if they select no to proceed
Case 7
Exit Sub
'if they select yes to proceed
Case 6

' Turn off screen updating.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ActiSheet = ActiveSheet

Selection.Copy

Sheets.Add after:=ActiSheet
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Find the last row.
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Check if there are at least two points.
If LastRow = 2 Then
    MsgBox "There not enough points to draw the polyline!", vbCritical, "Points Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if AutoCAD is open.
On Error Resume Next
Set acadApp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

'If AutoCAD is not opened create a new instance and make it visible.
If acadApp Is Nothing Then
    Set acadApp = New AcadApplication
    acadApp.Visible = True
End If

'Check if there is an active drawing.
On Error Resume Next
Set acadDoc = acadApp.ActiveDocument
On Error GoTo 0

'No active drawing found. Create a new one.
If acadDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set acadDoc = acadApp.Documents.Add
    acadApp.Visible = True
End If

'Get the array size.
ReDim dblCoordinates(2 * (LastRow - 1) - 1)

'Pass the coordinates to array.
k = 0
For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To 2
        dblCoordinates(k) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
Next i

'Get coordinates for bottom left and top right of the coordinates.
min1 = WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns(1)) 'minimum easting from column 1
max1 = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(1)) 'max easting from column 1
min2 = WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns(2)) 'min easting from column 2
max2 = WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(2)) 'max easting from column 2

minbound(0) = min1: minbound(1) = min2: minbound(2) = 0
maxbound(0) = max1: maxbound(1) = max2: maxbound(2) = 0

'Draw the polyline either at model space or at paper space.
If acadDoc.ActiveSpace = acModelSpace Then
    Set acadPol = acadDoc.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(dblCoordinates)
Else
    Set acadPol = acadDoc.PaperSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(dblCoordinates)
End If

'Zoom extent to newly drawn polyline.
acadApp.Application.ZoomWindow minbound, maxbound

'Leave the polyline open (the last point is not connected with the first point).
'Set the next line to true if you need to connect the last point with the first one.
acadPol.Closed = False
acadPol.Update

'Delete current sheet.
Call delsh

'Activate active worksheet.
ActiSheet.Activate

'Inform the user that the polyline was created.
MsgBox "The polyline was successfully created!", vbInformation, "Finished"

End Select

' Turn on screen updating.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I want to do is to add custom context menu in windows explorer so that I don't have to open the log file in excel.

Googling result is https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/ . But I don't know how to make it open the log file in excel and then run the code.

What I do now is set the default program to open the .npd files with excel, and add some more code:

```
Sub openfileplinetocad()
' Macro1 Macro
'
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("C2:D2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Call drawplinecad

Application.SendKeys ("%fx")

End Sub
```

However, if I can figure out how to add custom context menu in explorer to run the code I can save three clicks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you tried to combine your code with event `Workbook Open`? Maybe you can try to figure something that as soon as you open the workbook with your code, then it executes your macros.

Comment: You might consider adding a small vbscript file in your "Send To" folder - it can read the passed filepath, then open it in Excel and run your macro.

Comment: `if I can figure out how to add custom context menu in explorer` to solve this issue you can use [[context menu editors](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors)] available for Windows 10/8/7. BTW, it would be better if you could tag the version of Windows you are on